# Why doesn't go locate my vendored library?

Tags: go

**package vpc_app/unit_test.go:**

```
import (
    "github.com/my-org/my-library/http"
)
...
```

**package github.com/my-org/my-library/http/http.go:**

```
package http
...
```

**File Structure:**

```
$ tree
tree
.
├── glide.lock
├── glide.yaml
├── unit
│   └── modules
│       └── vpc
│           └── vpc-app
│               └── unit_test.go
└── vendor
    └── github.com
        └── my-org
            └── my-library
                ├── http
                │   └── http.go
```

**Problem:**

When I run `go test ./...` I get this error:

```
vendor/github.com/my-org/my-library/url_checker.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/my-org/my-library/http" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/my-org/my-library/http (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/josh/go/src/github.com/my-org/my-library/http (from $GOPATH)
```

**Question:**

I'm using go 1.6, but it doesn't seem to look in my vendor directory to find the package. Any ideas on why that might be?

**Update #1:**
As requested, here's my `go env` output:

```
OARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/josh/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Comment: Thanks josh, can you also show the first several lines in `vendor/github.com/my-org/my-library/url_checker.go` ?

Comment: And the updated error if it's different.

Comment: Ok, so I'm doing something really dumb. My repo isn't in my `GOPATH`!  Moving by git repo to `GOPATH/src/github.com/my-org/my-library` did the trick. Thanks so much for your help and responsiveness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My repo wasn't located in the `GOPATH`. Moving it to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/my-org/my-library` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

That error is originating from `vendor/github.com/my-org/my-library/url_checker.go` which is in your vendor folder.

It looks like it *is* finding the vendor folder, but the issue is due to an import statement in `vendor/github.com/my-org/my-library/url_checker.go` on line 7

Investigating to see if there is an issue with recursive dependencies with vendor folders.

Just to be clear can you provide the output of `go env`?

Comment: You're correct that `go test` is finding the vendored directories, and I believe there was an issue with the offending file (referencing a package that didn't exist), but even when I update that it still doesn't work. In this case, the issue is the vendored file was referencing another file in its library that was incorrect. Is my changing this inline not sufficient to fix the problem?